# “ate an animal raw” or “ate a raw animal”

Tags: grammar, meaning, adjectives

[To Kill a Mockingbird](https://books.google.ca/books?id=PGR2AwAAQBAJ&pg=PT20&dq=%E2%80%9Can%20animal%20raw%E2%80%9D%20harper%20lee&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwii-7iy0eTeAhXQrVMKHasRAT4Q6AEISjAH#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%9Can%20animal%20raw%E2%80%9D%20harper%20lee&f=false)

- “if you ate an **animal raw**, you could never wash the blood off.”

I want to know the difference between

> - I ate a **raw animal** ...               and
> - I ate an **animal raw**.

Comment: Normally, we don't say that people  eat an animal but that they eat meat from the animal.  The person described in the book is thought to be rather wild.

Comment: I got your point, but do you think that “raw” in this sentence acts like an adverb!. I was just thinking about it, and I came into a conclusion, but I am not completely sure of it. Sometimes, when a writer tries to emphasize on a part of a word, they might use a different structure to accentuate “the condition of that thing”. For instance, I bought a car cheap and new. In this sentence, I don’t only want to stress on car, but mostly on the condition of the car whether it is new or old, or it is expensive or cheap. What do you think about my point!? Does it make sense in your opinion. @Tᴚoɯɐuo

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, if you **eat an animal raw** the sentence structure is **{eat | verb} {an animal | object} {adverb | raw}**. Meanwhile, the structure for **eat a raw animal** is **{eat | verb} {a raw animal | object}**.

Semantically there is no difference, they mean the same thing.

Comment: But raw isn’t an adverb. It’s an adjective.

Comment: Sometimes you can use an adjective as an adverb. There's a good post on ELU about that here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56563/using-short-adjectives-as-adverbs-such-as-easy-short